How to reformat a plot legend to say actual Dates, but keep DOY?
I am wanting to plot timeseries data of lake depth(y axis) and temperature (x axis) for multiple years (2021-2023).
Due to multiple sample collection dates in one month I want to colour/fill by Day of Year(DOY) to distinguish each sampling date, but I want to reformat the legend bar to say the actual Dates.
I am still new to Stack Overflow so my apologies for my question formatting.
Example DataFrame with type of data I am working with. This is a subset of the year 2021, but I have data for 2021-2023.
library(tidyverse)

Temperature <- tibble(Depth = (c('1' ,'2', '3' , '1', '2', '3')),
Date = c('1/18/2021', '1/18/2021', '1/18/2021', '3/11/2021', '3/11/2021', '3/11/2021'),
DOY = c('18', '18', '18', '70', '70', '70'),
Temp = c('1', '2.5', '3.5', '1.2', '2.0', '2.5'))

Temperature %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Temp, y = Depth, colour = DOY, group = DOY))+
geom_point()+
geom_path()+
scale_y_reverse(limits = c(5,0)) +
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,4))+
theme_bw()

I'm also attaching an example of the plot I have.enter image description here

Maybe easiest to make a variable that is a date (in one single year, such as 2024) based on DOY:
Temperature %>%
  mutate(across(c(Depth, DOY, Temp), as.numeric)) |>
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) |>
  mutate(DOY2 = ymd(20231231) + DOY) |>
  
  ggplot(aes(x = Temp, y = Depth, colour = DOY2, group = DOY2))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_path()+
  scale_y_reverse(limits = c(5,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,4))+
  theme_bw()


Or this might be a good place for using the geomtextpath package:
...
geomtextpath::geom_textpath(aes(label = format(DOY2, "%b %d")), 
                            vjust = -0.5) +


Of if you want to use a custom palette, you may need to specify the date labeling. (Under the hood, dates in R are the number of days since Jan 1, 1970, and sometimes the "dateness" of your number might not get carried over to the color scale.) For example:
scale_color_viridis_c(labels = \(x) as_date(x, origin = lubridate::origin) |>
                      format("%b %d")) +



Thank you. Both options are working on my end. My issue now is when I try to apply a different colour scale (E.g. scale_color_viridis()) the Mar/Feb dates in the legend are gone and have turned to random numbers.
Any thoughts on which colour scale/pallet would work best with this data type?

I think it depends on your goals. Does the relative ordering or distance between dates matter, or just their differentiation? If the latter, then maybe a discrete scale would be best, where you convert your dates to factors. That would take care of the labeling too, since you could just change the factor labels to whatever you like.

To keep the date as is with another palette function like scale_color_viridis_c(), you may need to specify the labeling function, e.g. scale_color_viridis_c(labels = \(x) as_date(x, origin = lubridate::origin) |> format("%b %d")) +

^ continuing the comment above about palette selection, it might also matter how many series you want to show, and how distinguished the colors need to be for your application and audience. In general, it is hard for people to distinguish more than about a dozen colors quickly and accurately. Direct labels would be better if you need to show more than that many.

If you have further questions beyond what you put in the original question, feel free to start one or more new questions...
